# issue with css important, when used with two class

Tags: javascript, css

I have a condition where we have below code. i want to overwrite tr:hover when class greyLock is used. how to implement it. i cannot remove background-color: #EEE !important; from tr:hover class.

```
tr:hover {
    background-color: #EEE !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.greyLock {
    background-color: #7A7A7A !important;
    cursor:default !important;
}
```

Comment: Use more specific selector, like `table tr.greyLock:hover`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: The answer here is to use a more specific selector - but in the long run, relying on !important will cause you all sorts of trouble. I'd try to remove that first and work around it second.

Comment: Simply `tr.greyLock{ .. }` [would do](http://jsfiddle.net/gvbtebs0/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!important` styles obey the same [specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) rules as normal css styles when trying to override them.

To make your `.greyLock` rule override the one from `tr:hover`, you'll need to make the selector more specific.

Depending on your HTML, something like this should do the trick:

```
tr.greyLock:hover {
    background-color: #7A7A7A !important;
    cursor:default !important;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Test with to redefine `tr:hover` on other css sheet and link on html before first sheet